# how to encrypt the data source password or data source in tomee

Tags: java, data-structures, apache-tomee

I want to store password in encrypted format so it is not readable for other user. my `tomee.xml` file contains

```
<Resource id="jdbc/myrootdb" type="DataSource">
         JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
         JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
         UserName root
         Password root    
         JtaManaged false   
          InitialSize 50 
         MaxActive 10
         MaxIdle 3 
</Resource>
```

I am using apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

The `<Resource>` in Tomcat has an attribute called `factory`. Here you specify a datasource factory. For encrypted password you need a custom datasource factory which reads the encrypted password. Here is what you need

1. An encryption/decryption algorithm for password.
2. Custom datasource factory

For more details, please check out this [very detailed step by step example](http://www.idesign4all.nl/blog/?p=103) for achieving the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download standalone version of OpenEJB
2. Go to `<OpenEJB install path>/bin` and execute the command
   `openejb cipher root`
3. Copy the generated encrypted password to your datasource resource definition
4. Add the property DataSourceCreator to your datasource resource definition:
   `DataSourceCreator dbcp`
5. Add the property PasswordCipher to your datasource resource definition:
   `PasswordCipher Static3DES`

For more information see: 
http://openejb.apache.org/datasource-password-encryption.html

Comment: this is not secure for encrypt password. because user can easily decry pt the encrypted password